# AngularJS : $q -> deferred API order of things (lifecycle) AND who invokes digest?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, deferred, angular-promise

The [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) is very powerful in angularjs and make our life easier with asynchronous code.

I am new to angular but using deferred API is not very new to me. I must say that I completely ok with the `How to use` part of documentation + there are very useful links for that within the docs + I checked out the source either.

My question is more about the **under the hood** parts of deferred and promise API objects in angular. What are the exact **phases** in their **life cycles** and how are they interacts with `rootScope.Scope`(s). My assumptions are that when the promise resolves - it invokes the digest loop ??? yes / no ?

Can one provide a detailed answer with specific respect to the following list of aspects:

1. What is the order of things that happen in each of your described
   steps / phases
2. When new deferred object with a new promise instance created - who aware of it / is it 
   important ?
3. How exactly the scope updated when promise object being resolved? Do i have to update it manually inside the callback or the digest will be automatically invoked and update the rootScope [like declared here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#differences-between-kris-kowal-s-q-and-q)
4. mention at least one approach of updating the scope from within the promise callback
5. I assume there a lot of other useful aspects, feel free to provide them all.

I will appreciate and accept the most detailed answer, with as much as possible references to docs or source (that i couldn't find by myself). I can't find any previously discussion  with this topic, if there already was - please post links.

ps: +1 for any one that will help by suggesting a better title for this question, please add your suggestions in a comment.

Cheers!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Promises have three states

- **Pending** - this is how promises start.
- **Fulfilled** - this is what happens when you resolve a deferred, or when the return value from `.then` fulfills, and it generally analogous to a standard return value.
- **Rejected** - This is what happens when you reject a deferred, when you `throw` from a `.then` handler or when you return a promise that unwraps to a rejection*, it is generally analogous to a standard exception thrown.

In Angular, promises resolve asynchronously and provide their guarantees by resolving via `$rootScope.$evalAsync(callback);` (taken from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L175)).

Since it is run via `$evalAsync` we know that at least one digest cycle will happen after the promise resolves (normally), since it will schedule a new digest if one is not in progress.

This is also why for example when you want to unit test promise code in Angular, you need to run a digest loop (generally, on `rootScope` via `$rootScope.digest()`) since $evalAsync execution is part of the digest loop.

#### Ok, enough talk, show me the code:

**Note:** This shows the code paths from Angular 1.2, the code paths in Angular 1.x are all similar but in 1.3+ $q has been refactored to use prototypical inheritance so this answer is not accurate in code (but is in spirit) for those versions.

1) When $q is created it does [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L173):

```
  this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$exceptionHandler', function($rootScope, $exceptionHandler) {
    return qFactory(function(callback) {
      $rootScope.$evalAsync(callback);
    }, $exceptionHandler);
  }];
```

Which in turn, does:

```
function qFactory(nextTick, exceptionHandler) {
```

And only resolves on `nextTick` passed as `$evalAsync` inside resolve and notify:

```
  resolve: function(val) {
    if (pending) {
      var callbacks = pending;
      pending = undefined;
      value = ref(val);

      if (callbacks.length) {
        nextTick(function() {
          var callback;
          for (var i = 0, ii = callbacks.length; i < ii; i++) {
            callback = callbacks[i];
            value.then(callback[0], callback[1], callback[2]);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

On the root scope, $evalAsync is defined as:

```
  $evalAsync: function(expr) {
    // if we are outside of an $digest loop and this is the first time we are scheduling async
    // task also schedule async auto-flush
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase && !$rootScope.$$asyncQueue.length) {
      $browser.defer(function() {
        if ($rootScope.$$asyncQueue.length) {
          $rootScope.$digest();
        }
      });
    }

    this.$$asyncQueue.push({scope: this, expression: expr});
  },

  $$postDigest : function(fn) {
    this.$$postDigestQueue.push(fn);
  },
```

Which, as you can see indeed schedules a digest if we are not in one and no digest has previously been scheduled. Then it pushes the function to the `$$asyncQueue`.

In turn inside $digest (during a cycle, and *before* testing the watchers):

```
 asyncQueue = this.$$asyncQueue,
 ...
 while(asyncQueue.length) {
      try {
          asyncTask = asyncQueue.shift();
          asyncTask.scope.$eval(asyncTask.expression);
      } catch (e) {
          clearPhase();
          $exceptionHandler(e);
      }
      lastDirtyWatch = null;
 }
```

So, as we can see, it runs on the `$$asyncQueue` until it's empty, executing the code in your promise.

So, as we can see, updating the scope is simply assigning to it, a digest will run if it's not already running, and if it is, the code inside the promise, run on `$evalAsync` is called before the watchers are run. So a simple:

```
myPromise().then(function(result){
    $scope.someName = result;
});
```

Suffices, keeping it simple.

<sup>* note angular distinguishes throws from rejections - throws are logged by default and rejections have to be logged explicitly</sup>

Comment: Thanks! And once again for revealing the relevant source parts! I will definitely accept this answer, completely perfect! I feel that i can safely move on now )))

Comment: @arty sure, enjoy promises - they're truly a useful abstraction. Also, it would be great if now that you understand how it works, you could support this proposal :) https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6697

Comment: This answer explained a lot. We were using deferreds in our tests and it took quite a while for us to realise that we had to digest once until it was resolved.

Answer (score 8):

> when the promise resolves - it invokes the digest loop ?

Yes. You can test this by a simple template:

```
{{state}}
```

and controller code that changes the `$scope.state` variable after a delay:

```
$scope.state = 'Pending';
var d = $q.defer();
d.promise.then(function() {
  $scope.state = 'Resolved, and digest cycle must have run';
});
$window.setTimeout(function() {
  d.resolve();
}, 1000);
```

You can see this at http://plnkr.co/edit/fIfHYz9EYK14A5OS6NLd?p=preview.  After a second, the text in the HTML shows `Resolved, and digest cycle must have run`. The call to `setTimeout` rather than `$timeout` is deliberate, to ensure that it must be `resolve` which ends up starting the digest loop.

This is confirmed by looking in the source: [`resolve`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_2/src/ng/q.js#L207) calls its callbacks via [`nextTick`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_2/src/ng/q.js#L174), which is a function that passed the callbacks to `$rootScope.$evalAsync`, which according to the [`$evalAsync` docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync):

> at least one $digest cycle will be performed after expression execution

[Those same docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsy) also say:

> Note: if this function is called outside of a $digest cycle, a new $digest cycle will be scheduled

so whether the stack is already in the $digest loop can change the exact order of events.

---

> '1. What is the order of things that happen in each of your described steps / phases

Going into the previous example in detail:

1. `var d = $q.defer();`
    The deferred object's promise is in a pending state. At this point, virtually nothing has happened, you just have a deferred object with `resolve`, `reject`, `notifiy` and `promise` properties. Nothing has used or affected the $digest loop
2. `d.promise.then(function() {
     $scope.state = 'Resolved, and digest cycle must have run';
   });`

   The promise is still in a pending state, but with a `then` success callback registered. Again, nothing has used or affected the $digest loop or any scope.
3. `$window.setTimeout(function() {
     d.resolve();
   }, 1000);`

   After 1 second, `d.resolve` will be called. This passes the callback defined in Step 2 above to [$evalAsync (via nextTick)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_2/src/ng/q.js#L340).
4. $evalAsync will call the callback
5. $evalAsync will then ensure one $digest cycle will be called.

---

> '2. When new deferred object with a new promise instance created - who aware of it / is it important ?

Only the caller of `$q.defer()`. Nothing happens with respect to any scope until `resolved` is called (or indeed, `reject` or `notify`).

---

> '3. How exactly the scope updated promise object being resolved? Do i have to update it manually inside the callback or the digest will be automatically invoked and update the rootScope like declared here

As mentioned, the $digest loop will be automatically started by calling `resolve` (if it's not in it already).

---

> '4. mention at least one approach of updating the scope from within the promise callback

The example above gives this.

---

> '5. I assume there a lot of other useful aspects, feel free to provide them all.

Not that I can think of!

Comment: I'm not really sure why you added another answer an hour later. Would you mind explaining what you think this answer explains that mine does not so I can better understand what you think mine is missing? Sorry, and thanks.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't think my answer particularly explains anything yours doesn't. I wanted to given an answer that tried to be clearer and focused on different things, by a) Using a short example rather than the source of Angular, with a working Plunker to see it working; b) addressing the OPs questions individually, especially regarding the order of what happens when a promise is created -> resolved; c) omitting the introducing about states of promises: the OP suggests this isn't required.