# then method of resolved promise not called

Tags: angularjs, promise, sinon, karma-jasmine

I am trying to stub a method using sinon, jasmine and $q.
I want that method to return my fake data.

The problem is that the defined `then` statement is never called and i can not figure out why.
This already is a simplified version but it still isn't working:

- The stub is called
- The console log `Steven Stub is called` gets called
- None of the `then` callbacks are called
- No error message

Here is my code

```
var p = {steven: function() {console.log('original steven');}},
    pStub = sinon.stub(p, 'steven', function(){
      console.log('Steven Stub is called');
      var defer = $q.defer();
      defer.resolve({item: 5});
      return defer.promise;
});

var promise = p.steven();

promise.then(
  function(data){console.log('Peter?');},
  function(data) {console.log('ERROR?');},
  function(data) {console.log('progress?');});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call a digest in order to resolve a promise. In Angular 2.0 this will be fixed, (and Angular 1.2 is slightly better here than Angular 1.1) but in the meanwhile you have to call

```
$rootScope.$digest()
```

In order to cause the promises to resolve. This is because promises work via evalAsync. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363014/angularjs-q-deferred-api-order-of-things-lyfecycle-and-who-invokes-digest/23363285#23363285) to learn more about how the digest cycle interacts with $q promises lifecycle.

Comment: Works! The Tutorials i found didn't do that :-/ Thanks! +1

Comment: @AndreschSerj glad I could help. I hope there will be a better solution for 2.0 :)