# Get state of Angular deferred?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

With jQuery deferreds I'm used to be able to check the current state like this:

```
var defer = $.Deferred();
defer.state();  //Returns the state of the deferred, eg 'resolved'
```

Is there a way to do the same for Angular deferreds? (or even better promises)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Update**:

Due to refactoring of $q this is now possible although not documented:

```
promise.$$state.status === 0 // pending
promise.$$state.status === 1 // resolved
promise.$$state.status === 2 // rejected
```

**Original**:

Unlike most promise libraries (Bluebird,Q, when, RSVP etc), $q does not expose a synchronous inspection API.

There is no way to achieve this from the outside.

You have to call `.then` on the promise and code in that handler will run when the promise fulfills.

Comment: On the bright side you can use a stronger Promise implementation  in Angular seamlessly

Comment: [how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984471/how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what version of Angular is this in? 1.3.5? 1.2.28?  thanks

Comment: It looks like it was added to 1.3.0 - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.0/src/ng/q.js.  I couldn't find any reference to $$state before that.

Comment: status can also be -1, but I'm not sure what it signifies? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.3/src/ng/q.js#L365

Comment: Properties start with "$$" should be considered as private API, and not used in your own code. However, there's not public API for exposing status of an Angular promise, I think.

Comment: @muttonUp: -1 appears to be a second resolved case, like 1.  It is used to signify when the resolved value is a function, or if the value needs to be passed down a promise chain.  I imagine -1 means something like "so far so good, but we have more code to run before the resolution is complete".

Answer (score 34):

The answer to your question is: **yes, there is a way**. The other answers nicely cover  the built-in limitations of **`$q`**. However, it's easy to add a state property to **`$q`** using **the [`$provide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide) service's decorator function**.

```
  $provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
    var defer = $delegate.defer;
    $delegate.defer = function() {
      var deferred = defer();

      deferred.promise.state = deferred.state = 'pending';

      deferred.promise.then(function() {
        deferred.promise.state = deferred.state = 'fulfilled';
      }, function () {
        deferred.promise.state = deferred.state = 'rejected';
      }); 

      return deferred;
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
```

Put this decorator inside of a `config` block, and all `$q`-instantiated *deferred* and *promise* objects will have a `state` property with the value *pending*, *fulfilled*, or *rejected*.

#### Check out [**this plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9y5TnQFCtiHoeidxpzfO?p=preview)

---

### Skeptical?

> *you are effectively modifying $q itself, wrapping every deferred with another deferred*

Actually this is not the case. **`$q`**'s original `defer()` constructor is called exactly one time. It is simply decorated with additional functionality by internally attaching an event handler via `then`. [Note that an additional `defer` object is instantiated as a result of the additional `then` callback which is automatically created with each *deferred* object... which is to be expected because this is how angular works internally.]

> *this wouldn't work because promises shouldn't be created with deferred but chained from promises that are returned from apis*

Note that this code will decorate **every** deferred (and thus `promise` object) which is created by the **`$q`** service. This means that **any API which utilizes $q will be automatically decorated with the `state` property**. So regardless of how you use `$q`, whether with some API or on it's own, this solution decorates both the `deferred` object and the `promise`, and I have provided [the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9y5TnQFCtiHoeidxpzfO?p=preview) to prove it.

---

### Production-worthy?

This approach is **unit testable**, it's **guaranteed not to break any application already using `$q`**, and **it's flexible** in the sense that you could later add additional decorators to `$q` without modifying the old one(s).

Comment: Yes this wouldn't work because promises shouldn't be created with deferred but chained from promises that are returned from apis

Comment: I've responded to your comments in the answer.

Comment: @GilBirman I know what a provider is :) You _are_ creating an extra deferred for every deferred (fourth line). That said, I give you points for creativity (although I hope you don't actually do this in Angular production code ;)).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I've updated the answer to explain why an additional **defer** object is being created, but not (as you thought) because of line 4. I don't use this code in production code, but it seems alright to me.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum This may be a dumb question, but I'm curious as to why specifically you would be uncomfortable using this in production code.

Comment: @NateBarbettini well - for one thing $q went through several big changes over the lifespan of 1.2, a huge internal overhaul between 1.2 and 1.3, and almost underwent an even bigger overhaul. Today you'd do this completely differently (deferred and promises are prototype based) - you could override `.then` directly without the overhead of this solution (creating an overhead and allocating an extra closure _for every single promise through Angular_) Promises are slow in Angular as it is (getting better recently).

Comment: I'm curious to hear the use-case of promises where instantiating a closure and some simple objects per promise would create any perceptible performance difference.

Comment: This definitely feels cleaner/safer than the solution in the accepted answer.

Comment: This isn't working consistently in Angular 1.6.4. This only decorates promises made via `$q.defer`, and not every promise is generated from that method. In specific, the `reject`, `when`/`resolve`, and `all` methods specifically call `new Promise()` internally whereas `race` calls `defer`.

The best way to handle this would be to decorate the constructor for `Promise`, but that entire API is internal.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated:

Unfortunately this doesn't looks like its possible with `$q`. You'll have to put this code inside your `then` method.

```
myPromise()
.then(function() {
    // everything in here resolved
},
function() {
    // everything in here rejected
},
function() {
    // everything in here pending (with progress back)
});
```

#### Other:

This is for the Q library not angular's `$q` but similar.

Angular is inspired by the `Q` library, check out the source, its actually not that scary. https://github.com/kriskowal/q/blob/v1/q.js

You can use `myPromise.inspect().state` there are `['pending', 'rejected', 'fulfilled']`

You also have:

```
myPromise.isFulfilled();
myPromise.isPending();
myPromise.isRejected();
```

Check out this JSfiddle and open the console for logged results.
http://jsfiddle.net/S6LzP/

More granular, Looking at the `defer` function on line 488:

```
function defer() {
    // if "messages" is an "Array", that indicates that the promise has not yet
    // been resolved.  If it is "undefined", it has been resolved.  Each
    // element of the messages array is itself an array of complete arguments to
    // forward to the resolved promise.  We coerce the resolution value to a
    // promise using the `resolve` function because it handles both fully
    // non-thenable values and other thenables gracefully.
    var messages = [], progressListeners = [], resolvedPromise;

    var deferred = object_create(defer.prototype);
    var promise = object_create(Promise.prototype);

    promise.promiseDispatch = function (resolve, op, operands) {
        var args = array_slice(arguments);
        if (messages) {
            messages.push(args);
            if (op === "when" && operands[1]) { // progress operand
                progressListeners.push(operands[1]);
            }
        } else {
            nextTick(function () {
                resolvedPromise.promiseDispatch.apply(resolvedPromise, args);
            });
        }
    };

    // XXX deprecated
    promise.valueOf = function () {
        if (messages) {
            return promise;
        }
        var nearerValue = nearer(resolvedPromise);
        if (isPromise(nearerValue)) {
            resolvedPromise = nearerValue; // shorten chain
        }
        return nearerValue;
    };

    promise.inspect = function () {
        if (!resolvedPromise) {
            return { state: "pending" };
        }
        return resolvedPromise.inspect();
    };

    if (Q.longStackSupport && hasStacks) {
        try {
            throw new Error();
        } catch (e) {
            // NOTE: don't try to use `Error.captureStackTrace` or transfer the
            // accessor around; that causes memory leaks as per GH-111. Just
            // reify the stack trace as a string ASAP.
            //
            // At the same time, cut off the first line; it's always just
            // "[object Promise]\n", as per the `toString`.
            promise.stack = e.stack.substring(e.stack.indexOf("\n") + 1);
        }
    }

    // NOTE: we do the checks for `resolvedPromise` in each method, instead of
    // consolidating them into `become`, since otherwise we'd create new
    // promises with the lines `become(whatever(value))`. See e.g. GH-252.

    function become(newPromise) {
        resolvedPromise = newPromise;
        promise.source = newPromise;

        array_reduce(messages, function (undefined, message) {
            nextTick(function () {
                newPromise.promiseDispatch.apply(newPromise, message);
            });
        }, void 0);

        messages = void 0;
        progressListeners = void 0;
    }

    deferred.promise = promise;
    deferred.resolve = function (value) {
        if (resolvedPromise) {
            return;
        }

        become(Q(value));
    };

    deferred.fulfill = function (value) {
        if (resolvedPromise) {
            return;
        }

        become(fulfill(value));
    };
    deferred.reject = function (reason) {
        if (resolvedPromise) {
            return;
        }

        become(reject(reason));
    };
    deferred.notify = function (progress) {
        if (resolvedPromise) {
            return;
        }

        array_reduce(progressListeners, function (undefined, progressListener) {
            nextTick(function () {
                progressListener(progress);
            });
        }, void 0);
    };

    return deferred;
}
```

Mostly notably the method at the very bottom `deferred.notify`.

Example usage:

```
function requestOkText(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onload = onload;
    request.onerror = onerror;
    request.onprogress = onprogress;
    request.send();

    function onload() {
        if (request.status === 200) {
            deferred.resolve(request.responseText);
        } else {
            deferred.reject(new Error("Status code was " + request.status));
        }
    }

    function onerror() {
        deferred.reject(new Error("Can't XHR " + JSON.stringify(url)));
    }

    function onprogress(event) {
        deferred.notify(event.loaded / event.total);
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

requestOkText("http://localhost:3000")
.then(function (responseText) {
    // If the HTTP response returns 200 OK, log the response text.
    console.log(responseText);
}, function (error) {
    // If there's an error or a non-200 status code, log the error.
    console.error(error);
}, function (progress) {
    // Log the progress as it comes in.
    console.log("Request progress: " + Math.round(progress * 100) + "%");
});
```

Comment: I think Angular's deferred's are inspired by the Q library but they're missing a lot of the functionality of Q: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q... From what I've seen those methods aren't available on Angular promises

Comment: My mistake, I've quickly looked through the angular github https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js and it looks like this isn't possible but you should still be able to use notify. :/

Answer (score 0):

I whipped up a solution inspired by Gil and Travis's answers, which decorates the Promise constructor with methods closer to the Q implementation.

Note that this decoration relies on `Promise.$$state`. This was built for Angular 1.6.4, and theoretically should work all the way down to 1.3.x, but no guarantees on that or future releases:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('your.module.name.goes.here')
        .config(configBlock);

    /** @ngInject */
    configBlock.$inject = ['$provide'];
    function configBlock($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$q', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
            console.log($delegate);
            var Promise = $delegate.prototype.constructor;

            Promise.prototype.inspect = function () {
                var inspect = {};
                switch (this.$$state.status) {
                    case -1:
                    case 0:
                        inspect.state = 'pending';
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        inspect.state = 'fulfilled';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        inspect.state = 'rejected';
                        break;
                    default:
                        inpsect.state = 'unknown';
                }
                return inspect;
            };

            Promise.prototype.isFulfilled = function () {
                return this.inspect().state === 'fulfilled';
            }
            Promise.isFulfilled = function (obj) {
                if (obj.constructor !== Promise) {
                    return true;
                }
                return obj.isFulfilled();
            }

            Promise.prototype.isRejected = function () {
                return this.inspect().state === 'rejected';
            }
            Promise.isRejected = function (obj) {
                if (obj.constructor !== Promise) {
                    return false;
                }
                return obj.isRejected();
            }

            Promise.prototype.isPending = function () {
                return this.inspect().state === 'pending';
            }
            Promise.isPending = function (obj) {
                if (obj.constructor !== Promise) {
                    return false;
                }
                return obj.isPending();
            }

            return $delegate;
        }]);
    }
})();
```