# $q.defer() creating a resolved promise

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, deferred

looking for some help on an issue that makes me losing my hair ! :)

I have to send a series of call to an API I consume. so I have created a factory with a function like

```
addItem : function(){
  var deferred=$q.defer();
  //call to the API
    .then(function(response){
      deferred.resolve(process(response.data));
    }, function(response){
      deferred.reject(errorManagement(response.status));
      });
    }
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then I have built an array with code:

```
for(var i=0; i<nbOfElements; i++) {
  arrayOfPromises[i]=Factory.addItem();
}
$q.all(arrayOfPromises).then(..)
```

My expectation is that the $q.all will resolve only when all calls to the API have been completed.
Unfortunately, it appears that this is not the case, and then I display a partial result, not satisfactory

after some debugging, it appears that the promises returned by the factory all have $$state.status = 1, which seems to be "resolved" state, explaining why the $q.all resolved before I would like.
([link to the values of $$state.status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091513/get-state-of-angular-deferred))

Still I find this weird as I have used this $q.defer() a lot, but without $q.all and it always worked fine

Any explaination on this issue and how to solve it would be much welcome :)

Comment: What does `process(response.data)` and `errorManagement(response.status)` do?  Can you please provide the code for them as well.

Comment: If you are seeing only partial results, then you must be suspicious that at least one of the `arrayOfPromises` settled with a rejection - ie an error occurred. To see what is going on, try logging errors in errorManagement()` and/or in the chained `.then()` after `$a.all(...)`.

Comment: In fact I checked in the console and it looks like all promises are resolved ($$state===1) before resolution... Weird ... Definitely weird !

Comment: The reference you link to says you need to inspect `promise.$$state.status` not `promise.$$state`.

Comment: yes that's an error, I meant $$state.status, I'm going to edit my comment on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return the `$http.get()` promise will actually work: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7o5a0zjn/7/).

If you want to do some pre-processing in the factory before returning the data (like your `process` and `errorManagement`), check demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7o5a0zjn/6/).

The `$q.all` callback function not invoked only after all promises are resolved. It is not because of `$q.all`.

Your array code has problem: `arrayOfPromises[i]=Factory.addItem();`. You'd better use `push` to expand the array.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I am looking at the second fiddle which works exactly as I would like, but I struggle to identify the reason why ! I'm going to dive into this to understand . thanks again for your help

Comment: Oh I've just understood what I had done wrong, some stupid mistake ! in my actual code, I was creating the array within another then() and the $q.all was outside of this a then, so was no asynchronous, and therefore was evaluating at the time it was executed based on an empty array... which was obviously resolved :D

Comment: In any case, thanks again for you help, I'm going to select your answer as it is still a good use case for anybody discovering the $q.all() function !

Comment: The second fiddle falls into one of the promise anti-patterns, the forgotten promise. Not that it won't work, just that there is many redundant code and there is a cleaner way of doing it. [Reference here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/#the_forgotten_promise)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can't solve your problem, just giving suggestions:

You can save a lot of code by returning the promise of your API call instead of creating new promises (this is one of the promise anti-patterns)

```
addItem: function() {
    //call to the API
    return $http(something).then(function(response){
      return process(response.data);
      // if you happen need to reject here, use $q.reject(reason/data);
    }, function(response){
      return $q.reject(errorManagement(response.status));
    });
}
```

I'm more comfortable on assigning into an array using push

```
var arrayOfPromises = [];
for(var i=0; i<nbOfElements; i++) {
  arrayOfPromises.push(Factory.addItem());
}
$q.all(arrayOfPromises).then(..)
```

You are not missing the part before `.then` in the `addItem` function in your real code, are you?

Comment: Careful with the error handler. You probably want `return $q.reject(errorManagement(response.status))` (assuming that `errorManagement()` doesn't itself return a rejected promise)

Comment: @Phil In my experience both process and errorManagement doesn't have to be a promise - they can be normal functions.

Comment: Yes, but OP appears to want to still return a rejected promise in the case of an HTTP error. If you don't use `$q.reject`, `addItem` will always return a successful promise, even if an error occurs.

Comment: @Phil Thanks, I've been misunderstanding how the return work in the second function of then. Edited answer for the correct way.

Comment: I will try this way tonight, thanks a lot. Will accept your answer then if it works ! Thanks again for the help.