# Using this within a promise in AngularJS

Tags: this, bind, promise

Is there a best-practice solution to be able to use within in promise this? In jQuery i can bind my object to use it in my promise/callback - but in angularJS? Are there best-practice solutions? The way "var service = this;" i don't prefer ...

```
app.service('exampleService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    this._myVariable = null;

    this.myFunction = function() {
        Restangular.one('me').get().then(function(response) {
            this._myVariable = true; // undefined
        });
    }
}];
```

Are there solutions for this issue? How i can gain access to members or methods from my service within the promise?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The generic issue of dynamic `this` in a callback is explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) which is very good - I'm not going to repeat what Felix said. I'm going to discuss promise specific solutions instead:

Promises are specified under the Promises/A+ specification which allows promise libraries to consume eachother's promises seamlessly. Angular $q promises honor that specification and therefor and Angular promise *must* by definition execute the `.then` callbacks as functions - that is without setting `this`. In strict mode doing `promise.then(fn)` will *always* evaluate `this` to undefined inside `fn` (and to `window` in non-strict mode).

The reasoning is that ES6 is across the corner and solves these problems more elegantly.

So, what are your options?

- Some promise libraries provide a `.bind` method (Bluebird for example), you can [use these promises inside Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984471/how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular) and swap out $q.
- ES6, CoffeeScript, TypeScript and AtScript all include a `=>` operator which binds `this`.
- You can use the ES5 solution using `.bind`
- You can use one of the hacks in the aforementioned answer by Felix.

Here are these examples:

#### Adding bind - aka `Promise#bind`

Assuming you've followed the [above question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984471/how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular) you should be able to do:

```
Restangular.one('me').get().bind(this).then(function(response) {
    this._myVariable = true; // this is correct
});
```

#### Using an arrow function

```
Restangular.one('me').get().then(response => {
    this._myVariable = true; // this is correct
});
```

#### Using `.bind`

```
Restangular.one('me').get().then(function(response) {
    this._myVariable = true; // this is correct
}.bind(this));
```

#### Using a pre ES5 'hack'

```
var that = this;
Restangular.one('me').get().then(function(response) {
    that._myVariable = true; // this is correct
});
```

### Of course, there is a bigger issue

Your current design does not contain any way to _know when `_myVariable` is available. You'd have to poll it or rely on internal state ordering. I believe you can do better and have a design where you always execute code when the variable is available:

```
app.service('exampleService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    this._myVariable =Restangular.one('me');
}];
```

Then you can use `_myVariable` via `this._myVariable.then(function(value){`. This might seem tedious but if you use `$q.all` you can easily do this with several values and this is completely safe in terms of synchronization of state.

If you want to lazy load it and not call it the first time (that is, only when myFunction is called) - I totally get that. You can use a getter and do:

```
app.service('exampleService', ['Restangular', function(Restangular) {
    this.__hidden = null;
    Object.defineProperty(this,"_myVariable", {
      get: function(){ 
        return this.__hidden || (this.__hidden = Restangular.one('me')); 
      }
    });
}];
```

Now, it will be lazy loaded only when you access it for the first time.

Comment: Thank a million! I didn't understand why I got this error. But right now it is clear :)

Comment: Great answer!!!. Could you please give a clear example on the last point you mentioned about $q.all??