# Is there a tool to generate flowchart from code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, promise, flowchart

I just joined a project made with Angular JS which has a lot of nested promises.
Some tasks seem to not happen in the right order, which causes some object to be overidden at some point.
I need to check how/when the promises are called, which are returned first, etc.
A flowchart of what's going on with all these promises woudl help me a lot, unfortunately it would take me quite some time to do it manually, so i was wondering whether there is a tool to automate that.
I've been looking on Google but can't find anything like that.
Any tip about how to trace promise calls/responses are welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, such a tool exists - unfortunately not for Angular promises, and it's not in production yet - it looks something like:

[image]

See [this Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/+UmarHansa/posts/XWHqThx8Tyj) for a short video.

Unfortunately for you it's not available yet. The other tooling for Angular does not support this use case.

On the other hand - if you [temporarily use Bluebird with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984471/how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular) and you use the 3.0 branch of bluebird - it will automatically warn you about out-of-sync issues like creating promises and not returning them, passing incorrect values and so on in errors mode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Photos (and code :P) by Petka)