# Avoid forgotten promise returns

Tags: javascript, promise, q

When I'm using promises to express dependencies between jobs, where the resolved value becomes unimportant, there is some danger that I might be forgetting a return somewhere. Example:

```
startSomething().then(function() {
  Q.all(tasks.map(function(task) { return task.startIt(); }))
}).then(collectOutput).done();
```

Here the `Q.all` returns a promise, and I should have returned that. Not doing so means that by the time `collectOutput` gets called, all tasks have been started, but there are no guarantees that they finished.

This kind of error results in a race condition, and may be extremely hard to reproduce and track down. So I wonder, is there some tool to help detect and avoid this kind of problem? Perhaps some promise library which warns when a function along the way returns undefined? Or detects promises with no listeners, the way Bluebird does for unhandled rejections?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that TypeScript can detect this "forgotten return" problem at compile time. That can be more of a change than you are looking for (you asked for a library, you are getting a suggestion to upgrade your language), but in my personal opinion, TypeScript is absolutely a worthwhile investment.

Comment: I find that using arrow functions without {} helps, since the return is implicit. E.g. `startSomething().then(() => Q.all(tasks.map(task => task.startIt())))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, **[bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)** will warn you if you created a promise in a handler but did not return it. If you're willing to drop Q.

Here's a more **[in-depth explanation about bluebird's warnings](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html)**

> ### Warning: a promise was created in a handler but none were returned from it This usually means that you simply forgot a return statement
>
> somewhere which will cause a runaway promise that is not connected to
>   any promise chain.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> getUser().then(function(user) {
>     getUserData(user);
> }).then(function(userData) {
>     // userData is undefined
> });
> ```

Comment: oh how I wish angular's $q would do something like this

Comment: You can pretty easily use bluebird in angular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984471/how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular