# typescript 2.1 with async/await generating ES5/ES3 target for angularjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, promise, async-await

I am attempting to use `async/await` in an angular `1.5.5` project.

Given this service method

```
    getDocumentTypes(): angular.IPromise<DocumentType[]> {
        var url = "api/document/types";
        this.$log.log(url);
        return this.$http.get(url).then(_ => _.data);
    }
```

I am attempting to create an `async / await` version of the method.

```
    async getDocTypes(): angular.IPromise<DocumentType[]> {
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    }}
```

> > Intellisense shows an error: `TS1055`    Type **'angular.IPromise'** is not a valid async function return type in `ES5/ES3` because it does not refer to a **Promise-compatible** constructor value.

Is there a correct way to use an **angular promise** in *typescript 2.1* with `async` / `await`?

Comment: where are the type annotations for angular coming from? could that be updated?

Comment: updating the typings has proved to be a problem as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216046/updating-angular-1-5-10-typings-global-vs-external-module

Comment: I have successfully updated the typings using `npm i @types/angular`. There is an interface in the 2.1 lib.d.ts called `PromiseLike<T>` but it's not clear how it might be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**async / await can work in angularjs 1.5**

if the `$q` scheduler is [swapped out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984471/how-do-i-use-bluebird-with-angular) with `Bluebird` promises.
By adding the following to `app.ts`

```
export class Module {
    app: ng.IModule;

    constructor(name: string, modules: Array<string>) {
        this.app = module(name, modules);
    }
}

function trackDigests(app) {
    app.run(["$rootScope",$rootScope => {
        Promise.setScheduler(cb => {
            $rootScope.$evalAsync(cb);
        });
    }]);
}

export var app: ng.IModule = new Module("app", []).app;
trackDigests(app);
```

The regular `$q` scheduler is swapped out.
Code like this works out of the box!

```
async $onInit() {
    this.start();
    try {
        var key = await this.powerService.getKey(this._apiKey.partyAccountNumber);
        var sites = await this.powerService.loadSites(this._apiKey.partyAccountNumber);
        await this.showSummary(sites);
        this.stop(true);
    } catch (error) {
        this.$log.error(error);
        this.stop(false);
    }
}
```

You can return `Promise` or `ng.IPromse` from your service methods, as they are interchangable.

```
export interface IPowerService {
    setKey(key: pa.PowerApi): ng.IPromise<dm.ClientSite[]>;
    getKey(partyAccountNumber: string): Promise<pa.PowerApi>;
}
```

By using the above `trackDigests` in the test harness, unit tests will also work with `async / await`
In my case, I added the following to my `webpack.test.js` to enable `async/await` to function the same way with **karma** tests.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Promise: 'bluebird'
    })
],
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to just use Promise directly:

```
async getDocTypes(): Promise<DocumentType[]> {

}}
```

*The typescript 2+ generated code, will fall outside of the angular digest cycle, and the component / directive will not update the view / model correctly.*

Comment: `Promise` is not defined.

Comment: Is that a TypeScript error or runtime error?  If TypeScript, you may need to add `"es2015.promise"` to your `compilerOptions` / `lib` setting in tsconfig.json.

Comment: this did not seem to work when I originally attempted it, with webpack.js, and ts-loader, and it seems to work with `Promise<T>`

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer: this answer works in 2018 with TS `3.2.2`. I am not sure they are similar in 2.1.

currently there are compiler options allowing libraries to be added to the compilation. To use async/await you have the next options:

- **command line**: `--target ES6 --lib es2015.generator`.
- **Config file**:

  ```json
  {
      "compilerOptions": {
          "target": "es5",
          "lib": ["es2015.generator"]
          ...
     }
     ...
  }
  ```